# Can the attentional mechanism be applied to structures like feedforward neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model, feed-forward

Recently, I have learned decoder-encoder network and attention mechanism, and found that many papers and blogs implement attention mechanism on RNN network.

I am interested if other networks can incorporate attentional mechanisms.For example, the encoder is a feedforward neural network and decoder is an RNN. Can feedforward neural networks without time series use attentional mechanisms? If you can, please give me some suggestions.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Feed forward networks treat features as independent; convolutional networks focus on relative location and proximity; RNNs and LSTMs have memory limitations and tend to read in one direction.

In contrast to these, attention and the transformer can grab context about a word from distant parts of a sentence, both earlier and later than the word appears, in order to encode information to help us understand the word and its role in the system called sentence.

There is a good model for feed-forward network with attention mechanism here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08756.pdf

hope to be useful.

Comment: What I understand by "a word from distant parts of a sentence" is actually the body of the attention mechanism is the different weight of each input, right? I also saw this paper after asking questions, which inspired me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is, If the answer helps you, please check it as true. Thank you too.

Comment: Have you read this paper? I'm a little confused about this paper, where is the time steps in the FNN? And as I mentioned in my question too, feedforward neural network has no temporal relation, so what part is used to construct when calculating the encode?

Comment: Yes I read it before. Actually you have a sequential data in time steps which you feed it as inputs. There is no temporal relation in FNN structure but the whole architecture incorporate the attention-based model will capture the relation. @Yilia.Zhang

Comment: Does this mean that after I add the attention mechanism, an FNN can accept input with time steps?  One more thing, attention mechanism can capture temporal relation which I can't understand, can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: I suggest this document for you to read it carefully: https://skymind.ai/wiki/attention-mechanism-memory-network , please read it and if you have more question I am here :) @Yilia.Zhang

Comment: I have read this document. Did you say that the architecture that can capture the temporal relation is Transformer? If so, I will understand in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08756.pdf) that attention is calculated by FNN, instead of adding such a mechanism in FNN as I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use attention / self- attention / multi-head attention mechanisms to other feed forward networks. It is also possible to use attention mechanisms with CNN based architectures i.e which part of images should be paid more attention while predicting another part of an image. The mail idea behind attention is giving weight to all the other inputs while predicting a particular output or how we correlate words in a sentence for a NLP problem . You can read about the really famous Transformer architecture which is based on self-attention and has no RNN in it. 
For getting a gist of different type of attention mechanism you can read [this blog](https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/06/24/attention-attention.html).

Comment: I've tried to read the core of the transformer, but there are some parts I don't understand.This blog is very helpful to me! But as I mentioned in my question, feedforward neural network has no temporal relation, so what part is used to construct when calculating the encode?